# Angular 7 AES encrypting password with crypt-js

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt the password using AES technique and sending it to api which is developed on .net. Issue I am facing is I am getting error:

I am using Crypto-JS typed version: [Crypto-JS Doc](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)

> Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

My typescript code is :

```
let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('Coll@123', '16ad55fd-598b-45d7-a371-a1e011ec1345', {iv: '6fcc45cc3a8a4764'}).ciphertext.toString();
console.log("Encrypted: ", encrypted);
let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "16ad55fd-598b-45d7-a371-a1e011ec1345", {iv: '6fcc45cc3a8a4764'}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
console.log("Decrypted: ", decrypted);
```

My .net code is :

```
public static string encrypt(string encryptString, string EncryptionKey)
{
    Cryptography cript = new Cryptography();
    string ivString = AppConstants.EncryptionKey_IV_Default; //16 character IV
    string key = cript.getHashSha256(EncryptionKey, 32);
    string cipherText = cript.Encrypt(encryptString, key, ivString);
    return cipherText;
}
```

Note: I have not developed the .net code I am consuming someone else API.

Please help I dont know what I am doing wrong here. Is there something which I am missing here.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Why exactly are you encrypting it before you send it to the server? The accepted way of doing this is to make the connection over SSL, that get a certificate and connect using http**S** which ensures end to end encryption between client and server.

Comment: Browser is that guy who never keeps anybody's secret. That's the reason in OAuth there is altogether a new grant type "implicit grant type". You have to keep your encryption key secretly. Browser can't do that. Please reconsider your design decision. Before going into cryptojs, please find out from the api owner: the AES mode (ECB / CBC / GCM), padding, key size, how to get the IV. Then it will be easy.

Comment: The api I am requesting to is developed by someone else and they have generated it using basic .net code snippet which I shared. The problem is I need to connect to those API using Angular/typescript but first I need to send the encrypted password in the request but I am always getting error from the server 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.'